# Android: Synchronizing Threads and Handler

Tags: java, android, synchronization, handler, seekbar

I am having some trouble with my App. I'm very new to Android development so i hope it's an easy mistake.
So I'm trying to write an app that gets some raw data via Wifi(first Thread), do some calculations(second Thread), create a Bitmap out of the calculated Data(third Thread) and update the Display(Handler).
Some Parameters are adjusted by SeekBars. Everything works fine. But sometimes when I change the seekBarValues the Picture isn't updated Anymore. the Threads and the Handler are still running so i dont't get an Error.

Here some Code:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private Handler outputHandler = new Handler();
    private SeekBar  seekBarBrightness,
    seekBarContrast,
    seekBarGamma;

    public static volatile double gamma = 1;
    public static volatile double brightness = 500;
    public static volatile double contrast = 500; 
    public static volatile double min = 0;
    public static volatile double max = 0;

    public static volatile boolean isRunning = false;

    public static volatile int r = 0;
    public static volatile int g = 0;
    public static volatile int b = 0;
    public static volatile int width = 400;
    public static volatile int height = 250;

    public volatile double inputExchangeFrame[][ ]= new double[400][250], outputExchangeFrame[][]= new double[400][250];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        seekBarBrightness = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarBrightness); 
        seekBarContrast = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarContrast);
        SeekBarGamma = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarGamma);

        newImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, BitmapConfig.ARGB_8888);              
        picture.setImageBitmap(newImage);


    }    

    @Override   
    public void onClick(View v) { 
        if(v==toggleButtonStartStop){
            if(toggleButtonStartStop.isChecked()==true){ 
                isRunning=true; 
                getFrame();
                calculateFrame();
                showFrame();
            }
            else{ 
                isRunning = false;
            }
        }
    }            
}
```

And the Other Methods declared also in MainACtivity:
getFrame():

```
private synchronized void getFrame(){
     inputThread = new Runnable(){
          public void run(){
               while(isRunning == true){

                   //inputFrame fron WIFI

                    inputExchangeFrameLock.lock();
                    //synchronized(inputExchangeFrame){
                         for(int x_1=0 ; x_1<width ; x_1++){
                              for(int y_1=0 ; y_1<height ; y_1++){
                                   inputExchangeFrame[x_1][y_1]=inputFrame[x_1][y_1];
                              }
                         }
                    //}
                   inputExchangeFrameLock.unlock();

                   try {                        
                        Thread.sleep(120);
                   } 
                   catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                   }
              }
         }
     };new Thread(inputThread).start();
};
```

calculateFrame:

```
private synchronized void calculateFrame(){
     calculationThread = new Runnable(){
          public void run(){
               while(isRunning == true){    
               //get Data from InputThread to applicate several Filter
               inputExchangeFrameLock.lock();
               //synchronized(inputExchangeFrame){
                    for(int x_2=0 ; x_2<width ; x_2++){
                         for(int y_2=0 ; y_2<height ; y_2++){
                              calculationFrame[x_2][y_2]=inputExchangeFrame[x_2][y_2];
                         }
                    }
               //}
               inputExchangeFrameLock.unlock();

                 //Do some calculations on calculationFrame  

               outputExchangeFrameLock.lock();
               //synchronized(outputExchangeFrame){ 
                    for(int x_3=0 ; x_3<width ; x_3++){
                         for(int y_3=0 ; y_3<height ; y_3++){
                              outputExchangeFrame[x_3][y_3] = calculationFrame[x_3][y_3];
                         }
                    }
               //}
               outputExchangeFrameLock.unlock();
               }
          }
     }; new Thread(calculationThread).start();
};
```

showFrame():

```
private synchronized void showFrame(){
     outputThread = new Runnable(){
          public void 
               while(isRunning == true){
                    contrast =  seekBarContrast.getProgress() +1;
                    brightness = seekBarBrightness.getProgress() + 1;
                    gamma = seekBarGamma.getProgress() + 1;

                    outputExchangeFrameLock.lock();
                    //synchronized(outputExchangeFrame){
                    for(int x_4=0 ; x_4<width ; x_4++){
                         for(int y_4=0 ; y_4<height ; y_4++){
                              outputFrame[x_4][y_4] = outputExchangeFrame[x_4][y_4];
                          }
                     }  
                     //}
                     outputExchangeFrameLock.unlock();

                     for (int x_14=0 ; x_14<width ; x_14++){
                          for(int y_14=0; y_14<height; y_14++){

                             //Calculation of r,g,b  using gamma, brightness and contrast
                          }
                          synchronized(newImage){
                               newImage.setPixel(x_14, y_14, Color.rgb(r,g,b));
                          }
                     }

                     outputHandler.removeCallbacks(pictureUpdate);
                     outputHandler.post(pictureUpdate);

                     try {
                          Thread.sleep(50);
                     } 
                     catch (InterruptedException e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                     }
                }
           }
     }; new Thread(outputThread).start();   
};
```

and the Handler:

> private Runnable pictureUpdate = new Runnable(){
>        public void run(){
>   synchronized(newImage){ 
>   picture.setImageBitmap(newImage);
>   }
>   }
>   };

I know thats a lot of Text. But I really don't know where to start searching and what I could do to find the mistake.

Any suggestions would be great!

thanks

Michael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are implementing a couple of threads, and the order of the operations you are trying to do is not deterministic.

For example, it is possible "showFrame.Runable().run()" executed before getFrame.Runable().run().

1. The "synchronize" key word does not help because when the work is down in separate thread. The synchronize function call will return, and lock will be released.
2. The "locks" does not help to make sure the right order as well.

My suggestion is to use AsyncTask, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html. You can do something like this:

```
private class ProcessFrameTask extends AsyncTask {

 protected void doInBackground(Object... objs) {
     getFrame(); // Copy the frame
     calculateFrame(); // Do your magic
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     showFrame(); // Post the result back to main thread
 }
```

}

No multiple threading and cooperation, just one Worker thread does all the work, and post the result back to main thread.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. I already had the AsynkTask solution in mind. But the problem is that the calculation part is very CPU-intensive and the Wifi datarate is very slow. My concept was to get new rawData from Wifi all the Time so that i always do have the actual Data in calculationThread. Only one workerthread would slow this down or am i wrong? Is it possible to do a while(true) within Asynktask or should I do "new ProcessFrameTask.execute();" in onPostExecute?

Comment: 1. Multiple thread usually does not increase throughput. Maybe it does if you have multiple cores, and you can do some test to see that. 2. If the bottleneck is wifi, and you want user to see the data as it coming in, use the java.util.concurrent for multiple threading instead of implementing your own.  A simple way is to have one thread waiting for data, and post to another thread to process whenever there is enough data.

Comment: So now I tried your solution. Unfortunately the same problem. Everything works fine but sometimes the picture isn't updated anymore after I changed any seekBarValue. I tried some USB-Debugging and now I got this Error: "OpenGLRenderer Cannot generate texture from bitmap". Is it possible that the mistake is, that my picture has less Pixels than the ImageView? I wanted android to interpolate automatically. But it seems that I have to do this on my own. Or is there any other problem.  thanks

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is. A stack trace would be nice. And, also try to separate the concerns by making sure you code works without any threading code.

Comment: I think i solved the problem. I'm not shure but I think the app wanted to create the Bitmap out of an Object that was marked for the GC to destroy. So the object was still there but could not be used to update the Display. Thats why there was no Error Message. Now I create a new Bitmap Object with every loop the Bitmap gets calculated and it seems that it works. I'll take the AsyncTasak solution you recommended. It's much easier to synchronize. So thank you very much. Helped me a lot!

Comment: Wired problem. You might want to post another problem just for that. You might want have two image in memory to swap then instead of creating a new image every time. Anyways, glad to see you are good to go.